# Ubuntu X mouse focus button issues - With Solutions

Tags: unity, xorg, mouse, 15.10, xinput

For years now I've used a Cyborg R.A.T.5 mouse and have always had issues with the mouse focus on new installs. There's plenty of info around to fix it but since I lost my original solution I can't get my configuration to work.
**Remembered a solution while posting this (See bottom), Still have questions but I hope my findings help others**.

While playing with `xinput` , `xev` etc I randomly ran `xinput --reattach 8 2` and the mouse would then focus where I wanted it to.  The usual method is to hit the *Mode* button several times until it interacts with the window I want.

Even using `unity-tweak-tool` to make the window focus follow the mouse has no effect.

`xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.5 Mouse               id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]`

`xinput get-button-map 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21`

It's strange as I can only count 14 different actions the mouse could possibly do, even counting actions that shouldn't interact with the computer.

`xinput set-button-map 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Disables buttons 13 - 21 which *should* stop the issue.

Looking at this:

`xinput --query-state 8
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
    button[8]=up
    button[9]=up
    button[10]=up
    button[11]=up
    button[12]=up
    button[13]=up
    button[14]=up
    button[15]=up   # Was DOWN before set-button-map
    button[16]=up
    button[17]=up
    button[18]=up
    button[19]=up
    button[20]=up
    button[21]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=2335
    valuator[1]=953
    valuator[2]=98`

Only differs in that Button[15] is now *up* rather than *down* (Any explanations?)

`xinput list 8
Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.5 Mouse                 id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 5 classes:
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 21
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" "Button Back" "Button Task" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown"
        Button state: 14
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: -1.000000
          flags: 0x2 ( preferred )`

Button[15] is *Unknown* So I would assume it's not configured for any action; so shouldn't interfere‽‽

I'm wanting to fully understand why this happens and also to help others diagnose similar issues with multi-buttoned mice. So any information on what the best (and simplest) approaches to fixing this would be most appreciated! Better yet; would be a solution I can easily commit to longterm memory!

Answer (score 0):

While typing this I remembered the original config file name I used; so Googled it ...

`nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/rat5custom.conf
Section "InputClass" 
    Identifier "Mouse Remap" 
    MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.5 Mouse" 
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 11 12 0 0 0" 
EndSection`

Could this be better refined?? Using something from [xorg.conf](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading9)